# k-Nearest Neighbor VS Similarity Search

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, similarity, nearest-neighbor

Is there any difference in these two algorithms? In a glance, they seem identical to me.

Let's say we are searching for images, then given a query image, one can search for k (=10 e.g.) images with a k-NN algorithm. In a Similarity Search algorithm one can search for for 10 images as well (10 something like a threshold I guess) and the results should be the same as with the k-NN algorithm, right?

[Example](http://venturebeat.com/2017/03/07/flickr-introduces-visually-similar-search/) of Similarity Search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main difference is Similarity Search is the feature/product, while k-NN is an algorithm.

Similarity Search is just saying "Give me the similar items", this is the feature. It does not say how it should be done.

k-NN on the other hand is an algorithm. It is not a feature, it is a [classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification) algorithm. It is possible (though unlikely) that Similarity Search will actually use k-NN under the hood.